# Required field during deserialization only

Tags: kotlin, jackson, dropwizard

For a data class in Kotlin - how do I declare a field to be required *only* when it's deserialized?

For example, a call:

```
GET /foo
{
   "foo": null
}
```

should be possible, but any `POST`/`PUT` on the same resource should require the `foo` field to be a `@NotNull` string;

```
POST /foo
{
   "foo": "bar"
}
```

Is it possible to declare this behaviour in the Dto/POJO class directly via validation annotations?

Comment: Ah, bad phrasing by me. I am using Dropwizard which deals with the bean validation.

Comment: Check this one: [A Setter Makes a Non-Public Field Deserializable Only](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not#a-setter-makes-a-non-public-field-deserializable-only)